# NodeJS base URL with path gets ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, apollo, apollo-server

I use [apollographql/datasource-rest](https://github.com/apollographql/datasource-rest), and I'd like to provide a base URL for my upstream services like this: `https://my.apis.com/service/`. At its heart, this lib [creates the final request](https://github.com/apollographql/datasource-rest/blob/b267213e84bf4b963a320a5ff3bcdc55f070f86f/src/RESTDataSource.ts#L268C5-L268C40) URL like this: `return new URL(path, this.baseURL);`

The problem is, that the `/service/` part of my base URL gets ignored, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL). Is there any way to change this behavior?

Example code:

```js
export default class SomeService extends RESTDataSource {
    override baseURL = process.env.ENTITY_SERVICE_HOST ?? "http://localhost:8762" // when deploying, the ENTITY_SERVICE_HOST will be set to the URL above

    async someApiCall(): Promise<A> {
        return this.get("/resource");
    }
}
```

In its current form, if I set the baseURL to `https://my.apis.com/service/`, `someApiCall()` would send a request to `https://my.apis.com/resource` instead of `https://my.apis.com/service/resource`